# Как проверить прокси сервер на работоспособность?

Tags: curl, php, proxy

Здравствуйте, хочу использовать прокси в curl, но как их можно проверить на работоспособность? жив ли прокси или нет...

Answer (score 2):

Отправить запрос через Curl к любой странице. Если получиш ответ то прокся работает.

Comment: только стоит ограничить ожидание ответа от сервера